# get keyboard value

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I have input text element, I want: when I write some symbol in this input, alert this symbol,
that is if I write symbol "a", immediately alert("a"), how to make this? I trying, but it not working

```
$("input").on("keypress", function () {
                setTimeout (function () {               
                    var search_word =  $(this).val();
                    if ( search_word.length > 0 ) {
                        alert(search_word);
                    }
                },200);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problems with the variable scope. `this` refers to the inner function..

Use this instead:

```
$("input").on("keypress", function () {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout (function () {               
        var search_word =  $(that).val();
        if ( search_word.length > 0 ) {
            alert(search_word);
        }
    },200);
});​
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwuGt/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input").on("keypress", function (e) {
    alert(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use keyup, it's fired after the input got the value, so you don't need a timeout.
http://jsfiddle.net/yF2hU/

```
$('#foo').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
});​
```